# Derivative of $\int_0^tf(x,t)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Derivative of $\int_0^tf(x,t)dx$? Fundamental theorem of calculus works for $\int_0^tf(x)dx$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^tf(x)dx=f(t)$$

but how about this case?

Comment: Suppose $F(x,t)$ is an antiderivative of a nice function $f(x,t)$ with respect to $x$. (It is defined up to addition by a function $C(t)$ constant with respect to $x$.) Then $\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(x,t)\mathrm{d}x=F(a(t),t)-F(b(t),t)$, which can be differentiated with the chain rule.

Comment: @runway44 can you give something only about $f$?

Comment: No, in general, you must also differentiate $f$. Try the special case where $f$ doesn't depend on $x$. What's the derivative of $t f(t)$?

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^tf(x,t)dx=\int_0^t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)dx~+~f(t,t)$$

> **Leibniz Integral Rule (Differentiation under the integral sign):**
>
> Let $f(x, t)$ be a function of $x$ and $t$ such that both $f(x, t)$ and its partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ are continuous in $t$ and $x$ in some region of the $(x, t)$-plane, including $a(x) ≤ t ≤ b(x)$, and $ x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Also suppose that the functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are both continuous and both have continuous derivatives for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Then, for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$,
> $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt\right)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,t) dt +f( x, b(x)) \frac{db}{dx}-f( x, a(x)) \frac{da}{dx}$$

Comment: Can I have something only in terms of $f$? But not derivative of $f$?

Comment: No, because for this case $~f~$ is a function of two variable $~x,~t~$. If you take $~f~$ is function of one variable, then  Leibniz Integral Rule becomes Fundamental theorem of calculus.